# How to make this graph of a converted polar equation?

Tags: polar

I need to recreate the following graph on the right side. It has to be in the normal, nonpolar axis.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! This would have been such a great question for pi day! You only need a parametric plot in polar coordinates with radius equal angle, and `trig format=rad` can be used here, then you plot `(\t:\t)` where `\t` is the parameter.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad,scale=2/pi]
 \draw[-stealth] (-2.5*pi,0) -- (2.5*pi,0);
 \draw[-stealth] (0,-1.8*pi,0) -- (0,3*pi);
 \draw foreach \X in {-2,-1,...,2}
  {(\X*pi,0.2) -- (\X*pi,-0.2) node[below right] {\ifnum\X>0\relax $\ifnum\X>1 
  \X\fi\pi$\fi}}
  foreach \X in {-1,...,2}
  {(0.2,\X*pi) -- (-0.2,\X*pi) node[left]{$\ifnum\X=-1 -\pi \else
  \ifnum\X=1 \pi\else \unless\ifnum\X=0 \X\pi\fi \fi\fi$}};
 \draw[very thick] plot[variable=\t,domain=-2.4*pi:2.4*pi,smooth,samples=301] (\t:\t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]